# Java toString() method override

Tags: oop, printing, tostring

With the two classes I am making square objects in preparation for my exam tomorrow. S1 is created using default and S2 via non-default. For some reason the it will print out all values excluding the Side as 0. Please help.

```
public class SquareRunner{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Square S1 = new Square();
    Square S2 = new Square(4);
    System.out.println(S1.toString());
    System.out.println(S2.toString());
}
}

import java.lang.Math;

public class Square
{

private int s, a, p;
private double d;
public Square()
{
    s = 1;
}
public Square(int side)
{
    s = side;
}
public int getSide()
{
    return s;
}
public int getArea()
{
    a = s * s;
    return a;
}
public double getDiagonal()
{
    double d;
    d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(s,2) + Math.pow(s,2));
    return d;
}
public int getPerimeter()
{
    p = 4 * s;
    return p;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "Side: " + s + " Perimeter: " + p + " Area: " + a + " Diagonal: " 
+ d;
}
}
```

Comment: When are you calculating the values for area, perimeter, and diagonal? You are not getting the value because at this time there is nothing there

Comment: also why do you have int side as a parameter in all these methods?  That doesn't make sense.  For example look at your get side method.  What is with the int side there?

Comment: Where should I calculate the area, perimeter and diagonal? In the RectangleRunner class?

Comment: You need to fix it in your toString().  But before you do that, you need to fix this int side thing you have in every method.

Comment: I took out the int side but how do I call the functions in the toString()?

Comment: You still have some other odd things going on in here, for example you declared d as a member of your class but then have a local d in the getDiagonal.  You need to work on this concept of OOP

Comment: all you need at the top of your class is private int s.  You can remove the a, d and p at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
public String toString()
{
    return "Side: " + s + " Perimeter: " + this.getPerimeter() + " Area: " + this.getArea() + " Diagonal: " 
    + this.getDiagonal();
}
```

If you want to print out the perimeter, area, and diagonal then you have to calculate those values to be printed.

If you want to print these out in your SquareRunner class then you can do this

```
public class SquareRunner{
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     Square S1 = new Square();
     Square S2 = new Square(4);

     System.out.println(S1.getArea());
     ...
     ...

 }
```

}

Comment: It now works, can you explain why this works? I'm somewhat new to Java, thanks.

Comment: So you created a class called Square.  When you created an instance of square in Squarerunner it calls the constructor.  Your constructor only set the value of side.  It did not calculate the area, perimeter, or diagonal.  If you want to print out the values for area, perimeter, or diagonal you need to calculate them first.  When you calculate them it returns a value.  That value is what you want to print

Comment: Since toString is what you have printing it out, then you have to calculate it there.

Comment: @Ryan Marvin What you are confused about is normal, but it is not because it's java.  What you are confused about is Object Oriented Programming.  I remember the days, but you need to go look into how this works.

Comment: So if I wanted to calculate it before hand and not have to use the "this." how would I do that?

Comment: "this" just means in simple terms just means I am referencing the current object.  See what happens if you remove it

Comment: I removed the "this" and it worked, I think the problem in the first place might have been the int side parameter I put in

Comment: You don't need "this".  I just do it as a habit.  You will see why one day

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how you can print out the values individually in the runner class